# How to convert "day,month day,time hh:mm:ss year" into date?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a column of time data taken that looks like that
 "Wed Aug 21 18:51:19 2019"
im trying to convert it to dd/mm/yy with no successin order to sort by date with no luck.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the right format to describe your string date.

Here it is `'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'`because you start with `%a`: abbreviated day of week, followed by a space then `'%b'`: abbreviated day of month etc.

The complete list of available formats can be found [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df= pd.DataFrame({'date':["Wed Aug 21 18:51:19 2019"]})
# convert to datetime
df['new_datetime'] =pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
# keep date part only
df['new_date'] =df['new_datetime'].dt.date
```